# Count all unique instances of a pattern in text file

Tags: bash, awk, pattern-matching

I have a file with several lines of text all of which begin with six hex digits, a space and then some text. Sometimes, this residual text begins with the character `X` or `Y`, followed by 4 digits, and a colon. Example:

```
72a0bf Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
703e80 X-2310: Duis nibh sem, sollicitudin vel nulla eu, facilisis pulvinar purus. 
21b6ac Nam ornare blandit consequat. Vivamus tincidunt eros consequat, egestas 
8961cb Y-0110: dui at, lobortis nibh. Sed sed felis vel felis euismod dapibus in vel erat. 
ce5dfe X-2310: Curabitur facilisis felis nec ante euismod ultricies at eget turpis. Duis 
fa5e8b ac dui ut elit volutpat accumsan quis quis justo. Donec luctus suscipit sem,
```

My goal is to find all unique instances of these `X***` and `Y***` strings. Now, if all of my records were of the form above, this is possible through, e.g, some `grep`, `awk` and other `bash` tools:

```bash
$ cat file.txt | grep -E '^[a-z|0-9]{6}[[:space:]](X|Y)-[0-9]{4}' | awk '{print substr($2, 1, length($2) -1)}' | sort | uniq
X-2310
Y-0110
```

The problem is that, in some of the records that **do** contain this pattern I am `grep`ping for (and **only** in those), I unfortunately have some instances of those `X***` and `Y***` strings inside the residual text, and those instances can be 1, 2, 3,... whatever number:

```
c8edc6 X-0101: at tempor tellus commodo sit amet. X-2489 Nunc id gravida est, in rhoncus metus.
fa5e8b Y-9410: ac X-1320 X-0101 dui ut elit Y-9416 volutpat accumsan X-0101 quis X-2000 quis justo.
e29ac0 Y-5751: Vivamus Y-0110 vehicula Y-2021 dolor X-0101 a pretium.
```

This throws a wrench in my script above since I'm only looking for the patterns near the beginning of the lines. I want to be able to find **all** of those (unique) instances of the strings `X***` and `Y***`. Any ideas? Only constraint is that it has to be a `bash` solution because of environmental constraints.

Comment: You could use `grep -o` to get all occurances of this pattern (one by line), and then pipe it to `sort -u` to find the unique ones.

Comment: Be wary of any `grep` solution as it'll probably output matching strings from locations you do not want to match on, e.g. test any potential solution against sample input containing the first line `72a0bf Lorem ipsum X-9999: dolor` or similar. `grep` is not a good choice when you want to match on a specific field, awk is better suited to that as it's designed to work on fields, and sed can often provide a decent solution too as long as it just requires simple substitutions on individual lines.

Comment: In pattern matching, it's almost always much easier to match the strings you want than to not match similar strings you do not want so it's important to post sample input/output that covers more than just the sunny day cases of strings you expect to match in the locations where you expect to find them.

Comment: Side note: `grep` and `awk` aren’t “`bash` tools“, they are separate programs independent of `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
$ grep -oE '(X|Y)-[0-9]{4}' file.txt | sort -u
X-2310
Y-0110
```

Explanation:

- `-o` output only the matching parts of the line.
- `-E` for extended regular expressions.
- `(X|Y)-[0-9]{4}` regex that matches any string starting with `X-` or `Y-` followed by four digits.
- `sort -u`: This sorts the matches and filters out duplicates keeping unique items.

Comment: That would undesirably match any of the following: `foo X-1111 bar` (`X-1111` doesn't end in `:`), or `foo X-1111:2222 bar` (2nd field is not an exact match for `^[XY]-[0-9]{4}:$`), or `foo bar this X-1111: that` (`X-1111:` is not the second field).

Comment: @EdMorton What about adding a negative look ahead assertion `(?<!:)` that the preceding pattern `(X|Y)-[0-9]{4}` is not immediately followed by a colon `:` i.e.,  `grep -oE '(X|Y)-[0-9]{4}(?<!:)' file.txt | sort -u`? Would that work for your example?

Comment: Neither BREs (used by sed and grep by default) nor EREs (used by awk by default and sed and grep with `-E`) support any kind of lookaround. You'd have to use a PCRE for a lookaround which GNU grep supports with `-P` but at that point you'd be better off using `perl` as there's still more you need to do than just match the regexp (restrict it to match on one field and output just part of that field).

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^[XY]-[0-9]{4}:$/ && !seen[$2]++ { print substr($2,1,6) }' file.txt
```

Where:

- if 2nd field has a format of `[XY]-####:` and ...
- we haven't seen this 2nd field before (2nd field serves as index of array; first time we hit this test `seen[$2] == 0` so `!0` evaluates as 'true'; successive matches have `seen[$2] > 0` so the `!(1+)` is false)
- the `print/substr()` strips off the colon

This generates:

```
X-2310
Y-0110
```

**NOTE:** this generates the output as the records are processed; if you need to guarantee the ordering of the output then pipe to `sort`

Answer (score 2):

I'd typically go to `awk` for this or anything else that involves matching on fields, but just for completeness: using GNU `sed` for `-E` and `\s/\S` plus `sort`:

```
$ sed -En 's/^\S+\s+([XY]-[0-9]{4}):(\s.*)?$/\1/p' file | sort -u
X-2310
Y-0110
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ grep -E --only-matching '(X|Y)-[0-9]{4}' file.txt | sort | uniq`

Does the trick.

Comment: That would undesirably match any of the following: `foo X-1111 bar` (`X-1111` doesn't end in `:`), or `foo X-1111:2222 bar` (2nd field is not an exact match for `^[XY]-[0-9]{4}:$`), or `foo bar this X-1111: that` (`X-1111:` is not the second field).

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following, taken inspiration from Mark's answer. Simple explanation would be:

- Checking condition if 2nd field is equal to `^[XY]-[0-9]{4}:$`
- And making sure array `seen` is NOT having any value previously of current of $2 then print $2 of current line.

```
awk '
$2 ~ /^[XY]-[0-9]{4}:$/ && !seen[$2]++{
  sub(/:$/,"",$2)
  print $2
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

**As per the question, what I understood is to:**

Find all unique strings from the given file which starts with "X-" or "Y-" followed by 4 digits.

I hope this helps:

```
grep -oE '\b[XY]-[0-9]{4}\b' file.txt | sort | uniq
```

### Explanation:

#### Grep

- **-o** or **--only-matching** :Print only the matched non-empty parts of matching lines, with
- **-E** or **--extended-regexp** : Interpret patterns as extended regular expressions (EREs)

#### Regular expression:

- \b...\b :defines the boundary of the text.
- [XY] :Either X or Y character
- **'-'**: character hyphen '-'
- [0-9]{4} : any number with length
  4.

FYR:

1. https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs
2. https://regexr.com/7n3ua

Comment: That would match `foo X-1111 bar` undesirably (`X-1111` doesn't end in `:`) and match `foo bar this X-1111: that` undesirably (`X-1111:` is not the second field).

Answer (score 0):

Similar `awk` idea, consuming the `:` as delimiter

```
awk -F '[ :]' '$2 ~ /[XY].*/&&!a[$2]++ {print $2}'
```

Comment: That would match `foo X-1111 bar` undesirably (`X-1111` doesn't end in `:`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'match($2,/^[XY]-[0-9]{4}:$/) && !seen[$2]++ && sub(/:$/,"",$2) && $0=$2' file 
X-0101
Y-9410
Y-5751
X-2310
Y-0110
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash without external programs:

```bash
declare -Ai matches=();
while IFS= read -r line; do
  read -ra tokens <<< "$line"
  for token in "${tokens[@]:1}"; do
    [[ "$token" = [XY]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]] && ((++matches["$token"]))
  done
done < /path/to/input.txt
printf '%s\n' "${!matches[@]}"
```